# Removing unwanted text from values added to dictionary during loop

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is one of a list of dictionaries I've scraped:
(my_dict is a global variable)

`my_dict = {'Name': [<h2>Christopher C. &amp; Jennifer H. Lamey</h2>], 'Phone': ['(256) 236-8889'], 'Email': ['office@servproanniston.com'], 'Website': ['https://www.servproanniston.com/company-profile'], 'Address': ['\nSERVPRO of Anniston, Gadsden and Marshall County\r\n1140 Deerfoot ParkwayRainbow City, AL 35906            '], 'State': ['AL']}`

I'm trying to remove the square brackets, `<h2>` and single quotes from the values of each key so that when I plug it into pandas as a dataframe the values will show up just as the text of each value.

Current code:

```
def clean_dict(my_dict):
    final_dict = ((x.remove("<h2>" and "'" and "[" and "]")) for x in my_dict.values())
    contact_list.append(final_dict) 


def to_csv():
    clean_dict(my_dict)
    df = pd.DataFrame(contact_list, dtype="string")
    df.to_csv("SERVPRO.csv")
```

I'm getting error:

```
File "/Users/justinbenfit/Desktop/Python/Roto-Rooter Scrape/SERVPRO_refactor.py", line 163, in <genexpr>
    final_dict = ((x.remove("<h2>")) for x in my_dict.values())
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Supposing `x` is the value of each dictionary I'm not sure why this error specifically. I've tried several other approaches and I'm stuck. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: No quotes around `<h2>Christopher C. &amp; Jennifer H. Lamey</h2>`, is that an ELement object?

Comment: `dict.values()` no longer returns a list, but an view instead, hence the error. Also `and` cannot be used in this fashion as it is a [boolean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) operator. As non-empty strings evaluate to `True` that is what you'll try to remove from `x`.

Comment: `remove("a" and "b")` is not a short form of "remove a and remove b", but it means "remove True". Any non-empty string means `True` when it comes to boolean operations.

Comment: Yes I forgot about the way and works. Is the solution to just create distinct boolean tests (one for "<h2>" one for "'" etc?) and pass each value to them one at a time?  @szuro Is there an alternative to dict.values() that would return the actual values I haven't found one. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JustinBenfit the easiest way would be to just convert it to a list like so: `list(dict.values())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the values of dictionary are lists, you could just reassign each value with the first item of the list in order to remove 'square brackets':

```
my_dict = {k: v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

To remove `h2` tags you could use [`.replace(<old_substring>, <new_substring>)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). Final function would look like this:

```
def clean_dict(my_dict):
    my_dict = {k: v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if '<h2>' in v:
            my_dict[k] = v.replace('<h2>', '').replace('</h2>', '')

    return my_dict
```